# Tensorflow attempting to load wrong version of cupti.dll

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use TensorFlow with Cuda but I am facing a problem.

I am using:

- Python 3.9
- Tensorflow 2.10.0
- Tensorflow_gpu 2.5.0

And for CUDA:

```
nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
```

According to [Tensorflow - Build from source on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows), those versions should be compatible.

But as soon as I run my training, I get the following Warning:

```
 W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cupti64_112.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_112.dll not found
2023-01-30 16:52:40.052385: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cupti.dll'; dlerror: cupti.dll not found
```

So it is looking for "cupti64_112.dll" and "cupti.dll" but can't find them. And I checked in the folders, they are really not there...

I downloaded the CUDA files from NVIDIA again and installed it according to this tutorial: [CUDA Installation Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0) with the same result, the files aren't there. Now my question is: What went wrong? What am I missing? Where do I get the files from?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: CUPTI is always in an `extras` folder. Find that and add it to your path. But this is just a warning and won't have any effect on normal functionailty

Comment: @talonmies: I know but they are not there either. Does it still make sense to add it to my PATH variables (I am asking because it is a company computer and I don't have permission to change the variables myself, so I always have to call our IT department for changes like that)? And there are a lot of downstream errors which I suspect are due to those missing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing tensorflow twice with different versions.

Please uninstall existing tensoflow and re-install the tensorflow using below code:

```
pip install "tensorflow-gpu<2.11"
#Because anything above 2.10 is not supported on the GPU on Windows Native
```

As mentioned in tested build configuartions below, you need to install `cuDNN 8.1` and `CUDA 11.2` for `python 3.9` and `tensorflow>=2.5` to enable **GPU support** in your system.

Please refer to the link to install all required [softwares](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) for GPU setup and add these to bin directories to your [PATH](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path).

[image]